# How can you transform an app.config from a second transform specification?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, configuration-files, slowcheetah

How can you transform an `app.config` from a second transform specification?

The existing SlowCheetah extension does a great job, but as far as I can see, it only works against the build configuration

But web applications can have two transforms, one for the build configuration and a second for the publish profile, which are applied to the original `web.config`

How can you replicate this for a desktop application with an `app.config`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio there are two levels of transformations.
 - Transform based on build configuration (i.e. `web.release.config`)
 - Profile specific transforms

The idea being that if you need to share transforms across profiles you can create a new build config and define shared transforms and then you can create profile specific transforms for the items which are environment specific.

To create build config transforms, you can right click on `web.config` and select Add Transforms. To create a profile specific transform you can right click on the publish profile (`.pubxml` file under `Properties\PublishProfiles`). For more detailed info see the doc at http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-web-config-file-transformations-3-of-12

Comment: @SteveC ahh i see. Yeah we had a feature request for it https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/86 but it hasn't been implemented